# function fastcgi_finish_request cost most of the executing time

Tags: yii, php

I built a site with yii + php-fpm + nginx. Then I tried to find the bottleneck with xhprof. The result of xhprof shows that in some requests(not all), function fastcgi_finish_request cost over 80% of all the executing time. It's very strange.

[Click to view the full graph output from xhprof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du0IR.png)

[Click to view the form output from xhprof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWZ1Q.png)

the versions I use are:

php: 5.3.8

nginx: 1.0.10

xhprof: built from its github source

Why does the function fastcgi_finish_request take so much time?  And how should I avoid this?

Comment: Do we have to guess the question?

Comment: Sorry that forgot to show my problem: why will function fastcgi_finish_request cost so much time and how to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: What's that CallLogFilter component? That's not standard Yii component. That must be some type of logging component. Try to disable it.

Comment: the first line of the postFilter function in CallLogFilter is fastcgi_finish_request(), after fastcgi_finish_request, we do some log of this request to a log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the php-fpm.org page:

> fastcgi_finish_request() is a php feature, that stops the response
>   output. Web server immediately starts to transfer response "slowly and
>   sadly" to the client, and php at the same time can do a lot of useful
>   things in the context of a query, such as saving the session,
>   converting the downloaded video, handling all kinds of statistics,
>   etc.

I haven't used `fastcgi_finish_request()` myself yet, but if the time, the server needs to send back the response output made so far, counts as "execution time" for this method in the PHP script; it seems pretty clear, why this function "consumes" so much time, because it depends on your server and client network connection (eg. ping).

Does the execution time vary when using a local dev-environment?